# SonarQube will not start up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I followed this tutorial on installing SonarQube on my Ubuntu x64 Server http://stuff.stevenreid.uk/2015/03/12/install-sonarqube-5-0-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64/. However, when starting up sonarqube (linux-x86-64), it gets shutdown before completing to start. This is the sonar.log file:

```
    Spawning intermediate process...
Spawning daemon process...
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[2] : -Xms3m
Command[3] : -Xmx32m
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[5] : -classpath
Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.2.jar
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=mgF7P7quzzwWQ81F
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=19955
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-lin$
Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
Calling native initialization method.
Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
Java Version   : 1.8.0_45-b14 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Control event monitor thread started.
Startup runner thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@4a574795, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
Send a packet KEY : mgF7P7quzzwWQ81F
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
read a packet KEY : mgF7P7quzzwWQ81F
Got key from JVM: mgF7P7quzzwWQ81F
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
2015.09.12 16:24:14 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/$
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOP : 0
Startup runner thread stopped.
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
returned from WrapperListener.start()
Send a packet STARTED :
Received a packet STOP :
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
calling listener.stop()
WrapperSimpleApp: stop(0)
returned from listener.stop() -> 0
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
read a packet STARTED :
JVM signalled that it was started.
send a packet STOP : NULL
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Received a packet STOP :
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32001.
JVM exited normally.
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
Server daemon shut down
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I already have the debug logging mode enabled, but I am unable to find out the error and fix it. Any help is appreciated.

I am using JDK 1.8.0.45 and the latest sonar qube version 5.1.2.

Comment: Does the sonar process itself generates any logs? What you posted above is the wrapper (tanuki), but it's not the server itself. What the logs say is that the server exits and the wrapper receives a signal for this event (`SIGCHLD`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the jvm the wrapper uses. I was previously using JDK 1.8.0_45. I changed it to JDK 1.7.0_51. So I edited my /conf/wrapper.conf.

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java
```